# How to encrypt data after saving it, but return original at least once in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, encryption

So, I'm new on a Rails 4 project and I must create a new way to authenticate users by API Keys. I need to generate them and then it must be shown only once to the user, and when it is saved in the Database, must be an encrypted value for security purposes.

This is my current class:

```
  class ApiKey < ActiveRecord::Base

    # Hexdigest the token's HMAC digest
    HMAC_SECRET_KEY = Figaro.env.secret_key_base!

   # Validate the token's HMAC digest
    attr_accessor :token

    #Relationships
    belongs_to :bearer, polymorphic: true

    #Callbacks
    before_create :remove_previous_api_key_and_return_warning, :create_digested_api_key,

    private

    def remove_existing_api_key
      # we need to remove all the existing api keys for the user before we create a new one.
      @user = Aim::User.find_by(id: bearer_id)
      @user.api_keys.destroy_all
    end

    def api_key_warning
      # this method must return a string containing a warning message that will be shown to the user right after creating the API key
      puts 'Please, save your just created API Key, it will not be shown again.'
    end

    def create_original_api_key
      # this method must return a string containing the original API key that will be used to authenticate the user
      token = SecureRandom.hex(32)
      token
    end

    def remove_previous_api_key_and_return_warning
      remove_existing_api_key
      api_key_warning
    end

    def create_digested_api_key
      self.token = create_original_api_key

      raise ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid.new(self.token), 'token is required' unless token.present?

      self.token_digest = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest('SHA256', HMAC_SECRET_KEY, token)

      digest = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest('SHA256', HMAC_SECRET_KEY, token)

      self.token_digest = digest
    end
  end
```

The data saved will be the result of the `create_digested_api_key` method and that is not intended. I tried using callbacks to return the original key before saving and inserting the digested key after saving, but despite it seems to work in the console, the original value is the saved one.

This will not have a controller to make crud operations in, the created API keys here, will be used to authenticate directly with the controller that handles that matter directly, so I could not generate the key in a create method inside the controller and return it from there. Any thoughts?

Comment: İ don't remember the minimum rails version for this but you can check the activerecord encryption for this. It will save the data encrypted in db and you can retrieve the original value when you query it. Here is the link https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_encryption.html#basic-usage

Comment: Thanks for the tip, mate, will check it out!